# Method with generic type using runtime type

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to migrate a database with entity framework at runtime.
This is how you would usually do so:

```
Database.SetInitializer<TContext>(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<TContext,TMigrationsConfiguration>);
            }
```

However I do not know TContext or TMigrationsConfiguration until runtime.

How would I execute this method with runtime types?

---

***Update 1***

@Alexander Balte's suggestion put me onto using the interface IDatabaseInitializer

So this compiles without error:

```
foreach (IDatabaseInitializer<DbContext> initializer in moduleNeedingMigration.initializers)
{
     System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(initializer);
}
```

However i cannot do this:

```
public IEnumerable<IDatabaseInitializer<DbContext>> initializers
    {
        get
        {
            List<IDatabaseInitializer<Module1Context>> list = new List<IDatabaseInitializer<Module1Context>>();
            MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<Module1Context, Configuration> init = new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<Module1Context, Configuration>();
            list.Add(init);
            return list;//Error cannot convert type List<IDatabaseInitializer<Module1Context>> to IEnumerable<IDatabaseInitializer<DbContext>>
        }
    }
```

**Note** that Module1Context inherits DbContext

---

***Update 2***

This compiled:

```
return list.Cast<IDatabaseInitializer<UpfContext>>();
```

However when i run the application I got this error:

```
System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`2[Module1.Models.Module1Context,Module1.Migrations.Configuration]' to type 'System.Data.Entity.IDatabaseInitializer`1[System.Data.Entity.DbContext]'.
```

Comment: Do you have a variable like `Type T` or it's inside a generic class `class Blah<T>`?

Comment: I have a variable at runtime

Comment: It is impossible to cast `IDatabaseInitializer<Module1Context>` to `IDatabaseInitializer<DbContext>` because `IDatabaseInitializer` is contravariant.

Comment: Yeah I figured that out when i did it. Any other ideas?

Comment: Maybe setting return type of `initializers` property as `IEnumerable<dynamic>` will help.

Comment: So how would i then loop though `initializers` and use `SetInitializer`

Comment: @AlexanderBalte Okay I setup a dynamic type but i still have to iterate through it and call `SetInitializer` I run into the contravariance problem again.

Comment: @MrJD, use `var` for `foreach` interation variable instead of `IDatabaseInitializer<DbContext>`.

Comment: I'll be damned that worked. @AlexanderBalte if you update your answer I'll mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 0):

If you know all possible sets of `TContext` or `TMigrationsConfiguration` you may create somethig like factory method which will return you `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` by concrete types of `TContext` and `TMigrationsConfiguration`.

Something like:

```
    private static Dictionary<Tuple<Type, Type>, Func<object>> _map = new Dictionary<Tuple<Type, Type>, Func<object>>();

    public static MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<TContext, TMigrationsConfiguration> CreateMigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<TContext, TMigrationsConfiguration>(TContext type, TMigrationsConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Type contextType = typeof (TContext);
        Type configurationType = typeof(TMigrationsConfiguration);

        Func<object> builder;
        if (!_map.TryGetValue(new Tuple<Type, Type>(contextType, configurationType), out builder))
            throw new KeyNotFoundException();

        return (MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<TContext, TMigrationsConfiguration>)builder();
    }
```

Dictionary `_map` should be initialized with all possible sets of your generic argument types. Like:

```
_map[new Tuple<Type, Type>(typeof(MyDbContext), typeof(MyDbMigrationsConfiguration)) = () => new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyDbContext, MyDbMigrationsConfiguration>();
```

Comment: I'll try using a IDatabaseInitializer<TContext> and get back to you

Comment: It's worth noting that I don't know all the possible sets. I'll be passed an array of Contexts with Configurations (or IDatabaseInitializer<TContext>s) - Im going to see if i can pass in IDatabaseInitializer<TContext> now